# Selenium Chrome Webdriver Security

Tags: python, security, webdriver

I have written a python script that logs into a webpage and the script itself stores my credentials. I am trying to determine whether running this script could somehow expose my credentials? Or is it just as secure as opening my browser myself and typing in my credentials? I would have presumed it would be no different to doing it manually, but I don't necessarily understand how my script communicates with the webdriver and if in that process my credentials could possibly be exposed. The Selenium documentation refers to a Selenium Server, but exactly sure how that works. An official reference would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your credentials is safe. selenium server acts as http proxy and sends your script http data , pass through selenium server before running in browser.

Comment: But is the proxy itself secure?

Comment: the proxy will run on your local machine but if you want to be sure about security trace your packet with something like wireshark and examine your outgoing data.

Comment: Thanks, would you by any chance have an official source that confirms this?

Comment: according to selenium documentation "If your browser and tests will all run on the same machine, and your tests only use the WebDriver API, then you do not need to run the Selenium-Server". use webdriver to be sure about ir